# SSH authentication issue with Thunar: Can open individual files but can’t open many files

Tags: linux, ssh, vlc-media-player, sftp, thunar

I have a server that I SSH into all the time. I have SSH keys set up, but I'm noticing a strange behavior with video files that I'm trying to edit with VLC.

As most know, with a program like [Thunar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunar), you can open individual files with VLC by double clicking in Thunar and you can also drag a selection of files onto a running instance of VLC to add them to a playlist on the fly.

This works as expected with local files on the `localhost`.

However, when browsing the remote server with Thunar, I'm able to open individual files with VLC by double clicking a single file, no problem…

But, when I try to drag and drop a bunch of files into a running instance of VLC, I get a prompt that reads:

> Please enter a valid login and password for the sftp connection to the server

Nothing I enter is accepted, even my remote username and password.

Why is this? Why can I open an individual file, but can’t seem to drag and drop many files to a running instance of VLC?